# Unable to build a usable yaml-cpp library (shared or static) with gcc 3.2.3 in Windows

Tags: yaml-cpp

I unfortunately am forced to use gcc 3.2.3 (MinGW) due to the 3rd party code base having issues with later versions of gcc.

With gcc 3.2.3, I can build a static library (yaml-cpp.a) just fine (by editing the CMakeLists.txt file to remove the 'set(LIB_TYPE SHARED)', but I can't link my application against the library.  It always results in the following error:

C:/MinGW_2/bin/../lib/gcc-lib/mingw32/3.2.3/../../../libstdc++.a(c++locale.o)(.t
ext+0x38c): undefined reference to `strtold'

I get the same error when trying to build a shared yaml-cpp library.

After searching the web for a bit, most seem to resolve this problem in their projects by using 'strtod' instead of 'strtold', but I can't find any reference to 'strtold' in the yaml-cpp code; so I'm at a bit of a loss?

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have access to gcc 3.2.3, but can you see if you can use `std::stringstream` and read in `long` s (or `long long` s)? For example, try `std::stringstream stream; stream << "5"; long n; stream >> n;`

Comment: Sure enough, that results in the exact same error.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work by defining my own strtold which uses strtod:

```
#if (__MINGW32__) && (__GNUC__) && (__GNUC__ < 4)
extern "C" {
  long double strtold(const char *__restrict__ nptr, char **__restrict__ endptr) {
      return strtod(nptr, endptr);
  }
}
#endif
```

Admittedly, it's quite hacky, but it gets the job done.  I wish I could check gcc's minor revision too, but this is sufficient for my environment where gcc 3.2.3 is the only version being used.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that internally, `std::stringstream` is calling `strold`. Unfortunately, this means that you can't switch it to `strtod` - you simply can't use that particular conversion.

Since yaml-cpp uses `std::stringstream` to do its conversion, I suggest removing the `long`-related conversions. In `yaml-cpp/traits.h`, remove the `is_numeric` specializations that have to do with `long`, such as:

```
template <> struct is_numeric <long double> { enum { value = true }; };
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I wound up removing every single reference to long in the project, and it still gives me the same error, after making clean and all.  Does this make sense?  Perhaps stringstream uses longs internally?

Comment: Hmmm. Can you use `stringstream` in general? (for example, just declare a `std::stringstream` variable - will it link?)

Comment: Nope - sure can't.  Same error.  Sounds like I'm out of luck.

Comment: Perhaps I can detect the version of gcc and implement my own strtold, which uses strtod?